# $Y_i=f(x_i)+e_i$ where $e_i \sim N(0,1)$ : what is the variance of $Y$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have $n$ $Y$s: $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$. What is the variance of $Y$ when $e_i$ are the only random variables and they are independent. I can for sure say that the mean is $0$, but what about the variance? is that 1 or does $f(x)$ have an impact

Answer (score 3):

If $x_i$ is fixed, i.e. not random, then $\operatorname{var} (f(x_i) + e_i) = \operatorname{var}(e_i).$

(But if, for example, you randomly choose an index $i,$ then $x_i$ becomes random, even if each of $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ is fixed and *not* random.)

**PS:** Perhaps I overlooked that you want the variance of the vector as a whole. By the definition in Feller's celebrated book on probability, if $Y$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector then $$\operatorname{var}(Y) = \operatorname{E}((Y-\operatorname{E}Y)(Y-\operatorname{E}Y)^T)$$
is an $n\times n$ matrix. The entries are the covariances. You have told us nothing about the *joint* distribution of $e_1,\ldots,e_n,$ so we don't know the covariances. If they are all $0$ (which would be the case if we could say that $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are independent) then we have
$$
\operatorname{var}(Y) = \begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{var}(e_1) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \operatorname{var}(e_2) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \operatorname{var}(e_3) & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \operatorname{var}(e_n) \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: This is only true if you are taking about the *conditional variance of* $Y$ (i.e. $Var(Y_i | X_i)$). It is certainly not the case for the *marginal variance of* $Y$( i.e. $Var(Y_i)$). The OP should clarify which they are interested in.

Comment: @CliffAB : I said "If $x_i$ is fixed, i.e. not random". Your question of a "marginal variance" would arise only if that were not so.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and since those were the very first words I typed, I wonder how you missed them. @CliffAB

Comment: I did not miss them. I still standby that statement.

Comment: @CliffAB : $\operatorname{var}(f(x_1) + e_1) = \operatorname{var}(e_1)$ and $\operatorname{var}(f(x_2) + e_2) = \operatorname{var}(e_2)$ and $\operatorname{var}(f(x_3) + e_3) = \operatorname{var}(e_3)$ and so on. Do you claim that one of those statements is false? Or all of them? Or are you saying something else? $\qquad$

Comment: I'm saying close attention must be paid to how things are defined in this problem. We have $Y_i = f(x_i) + e_i$, and we are asking for Var$(Y)$. Var($Y$) = $E[Y^2]$ - $E[Y]^2$. Note that $E[Y]$ is a single constant which cannot change with $x$, unless we condition on it. Think of the marginal variance of the response and the conditional variance in linear regression.

Comment: ok, You're saying the variance of the vector-valued random variable. I'll look at that.....

Comment: But notice the typographical difference between $E[Y^2]$ - $E[Y]^2$ and $E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2.$ A hyphen is not the same thing as a minus sign.